# Conditional Query based on Variable value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

I am building a list view page with multiple filters using .net core as backend and mongodb as database. I want to filter data based on some condition such that if the variable is passed as blank, it should retrieve all data, otherwise only the matching data.

In mssql this can be achieved easily by

```
where (@SymbolCode = '' or SymbolCode = @SymbolCode)
```

What is the option in mongodb filter

```
var filter = new BsonDocument
{   
    {
        "symbolCode", SymbolCodeSearchString // If string SymbolCodeSearchString is blank, it should retrieve all data else the search data
    }
};
```

Sample Data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ed91bc65675f966c0eec46"
    },
    "symbolCode": "F",
    "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2021-07-13T13:14:35.909Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: @RABI construct the query programatically (for example a for loop, that starts with empty filter and adds dynamically that filters), and when done send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out. Thanks to @Naimi and @Takis. Building a dynamic filter is the key. Posting here the answer so that it could help anyone

```
var filterQuery = new BsonDocument
{
   {
    "symbolCode", new BsonDocument
     {
       { "$regex", SymbolCodeString},
       { "$options", "i"}
      }
    }
};

if (fromDate != "" && toDate != "")
{
  BsonElement dateFilter = new("timestamp", new BsonDocument
  {
     { "$gt", fromDate},
     { "$lt", toDate}
   });
   filterQuery.Add(dateFilter); 
}
```

By this way, i am able to add any number of filters dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you should check symboleCode before query on mongodb
first check if symbolCode is empty or ""
define filter query as

```
var filter = new BsonDocument
{   
    
};
```

else if it was not empty

```
var filter = new BsonDocument
{   
    {
        "symbolCode", SymbolCodeSearchString // If string SymbolCodeSearchString is blank, it should retrieve all data else the search data
    }
};
```

Comment: I believe my question was confusing. The answer you gave is to check whether the value in database is "", instead i want to remove this filter when the variable SymbolCodeSearchString  is "". Updated the question

Comment: let me know you want to get all data if symbolCode = "" not matter what is the symbolCode , and if symbolCode is F just return data with symbokCode of F ?

Comment: Exactly!! That is my requirement. If the search string is empty, i must get all data.. which means the filter should be omited

Comment: The answer you posted is good if i have only 1 filter. But i have many filters and it cant be handled this way. There will be many search parameters and any of it could be blank or with value. So if there is value in any of it, that filter must be applied

Comment: I dont familiar with the dot net core , but my solution is create the mother filter query and assigne data to it after that check the filter object each key has a null value remove from object and pass object to mongo as query